# JS-Joda / LocalTime support for days with more than 24 hours

Tags: javascript, time, gtfs, threetenbp, js-joda

GTFS feeds do not operate on the basis of a 24 hour day, for instance a trip that departs at 23:00 may arrive at 24:30 ([more details](https://developers.google.com/transit/gtfs/reference/#stop_timestxt)).

LocalTime only supports 24 hour days - is there another construct that does support days with more than 24 hours? I was thinking about extending LocalDate to add support but I can see there are many inbuilt assumptions about there being a specific length of the day. It does not look easy to change those.

For reference I am using the JS port of threetenbp ([js-joda](https://js-joda.github.io/js-joda/)).

Comment: I don't know how well the format support of js-joda is, but in principle: You should use lenient parsing because hour values of more than 24 are not supported at all in ThreetenBP (and hence should not be supported in js-joda which says that it is based on ThreetenBP). For formatting, you will need a manual workaround.

Comment: What is your end goal, I handle this GTFS problem with Java on the server side. What are your inputs, I gather one is a time in the format HH:mm which could be 25:30 for example, is the other a javascript date object representing the current time ? And what is your desired output, is it simply a javascript date object ?

Comment: Ideally I'd like a LocalTime object. I'm using it's isBefore/isAfter methods